# Open-Source billing software for grocery shop with hardware support

Tags: open-source, inventory, barcode, shopping, erp

My friend has owned grocery shop and he wanted to computerize his business he has estimate of hardwares :

Barcode printer TSC 244 Pro.

Honeywell 5145 barcode scanner. 
So is there Open-Source billing software for grocery shop which can support above hardwares? Either for linux(debian based) or windows), he need ERP like inventory and stock maintenance.

Comment: Those are least requirements I have mentioned.

Comment: How about Openbravo?